# breadth first maze generator doesn't generate "solveable maze"

Tags: python, generator, breadth-first-search, maze

I've been working on a project that requires randomized maze generation. After reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) on it I decided to use a breadth search first algorithm based on the one provided [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_backtracker). Unfortunately, after a few tests with drawing to the GUI, I've noticed that sometimes the mazes generated aren't "solveable" i.e. you can't draw a path from the starting cell to the "final cell". More accurately, the breadth first search algorithm described in the wiki doesn't actually account for an ending point! I just realized this now and am wondering if there is a way to fix this?

**OVERALL QUESTION:** Is there a way to ensure a path from a specified starting cell ([0,0] in this case) to a specified ending cell (let's say [x,y]) in a breadth first search maze generation algorithm?

Here is the python source code (as you can see it doesn't account for the ending cell)

```
def gen_maze(self):
    current_loc = (0,0) #initial cell is (0,0)
    visited = set([(0,0)])
    stack = []

    while len(visited) != len(self.grid):
        neighbours = self.get_neighbours(current_loc, visited)

        if neighbours != set():
            neighbour = unlist(random.sample(neighbours, 1)) 
            stack += [current_loc] 
            self.remove_wall_btwn(current_loc, neighbour)
            current_loc = neighbour
            visited.add(current_loc)
        elif stack != []:
            current_loc = stack.pop()
        else:
            current_loc = self.get_rand_loc(visited)
            visited.add(current_loc)
```

Most of the code is pretty self-explanatory (mirrors wikipedia pseudocode). A thing to note is that locations (x,y) are really scalars which are multiplied by the actual width of a maze cell later in the canvas drawing code.

Comment: Try looking and Primm's or Kruskal's algorithms on that wiki page.

Comment: @alecbenzer Will those algos guarantee that from a specified starting point (0,0) I can get to a specified end point (x,y)? I read over those but I don't really see anything there that sets them apart in this regard over breadth first search.

Comment: It seems to me your algorithm will "visit" every cell of the gird... so every cell should end up reachable from the start, no?  Why doesn't it?  EDIT: ah, `get_rand_loc(visited)` returns a random cell that _was_ or that _wasn't_ visited?  I think it should return a random already-visited cell, otherwise indeed it starts a disconnected component.